# how to scroll over range of floating action menu

Tags: android, scroll, overlap, floating-action-menu

[image]

The red zone is scrollView, blue zone is floating action menu.

The problem is that I can't scroll if I touch on blue area.

I want to scroll scrollView anywhere, green zone or blue zone.

How can I resolve this problem.

This is xml file of MainActivity code.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_qr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            app:fab_label="QR코드"/>

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            app:fab_label="연락처로 추가"/>


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
            app:fab_label="카카오톡 ID로 추가"/>


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_recommend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
            app:fab_label="추천친구"/>

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</FrameLayout>
```

and code of viewPager

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="친구"/>

    <!--<ListView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/listView"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent">-->
    <!--</ListView>-->
    <com.example.kakaotalk3.NonScrollListView

        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.kakaotalk3.NonScrollListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue has been [reported here](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/issues/186) already. Please have a look.

I am quoting the problem and the solution reported in that issue.

> I find what cause this problem. In my code it was onClick listener for
>   all fab_menu. It override all touches even when fab menu is closed. So
>   if you need this listener, you need manually turn listener on when fab
>   menu is open and turn listener off when it closed. After I remove
>   listener fab menu works great.

Hence I would like to suggest to override the `onMenuToggleListener` like the following and disable the on click listeners on your fab buttons when the menu is in closed state.

```
fabMenu.setOnMenuToggleListener(new FloatingActionMenu.OnMenuToggleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMenuToggle(boolean opened) {
        if (opened) {

        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't register click listener on fab menu

like - fabm.setOnClickListener(this);

if you register then remove it, Hopefully, it will work fine!